# jQuery: computation on dynamic table generated from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've made a dynamic table generated using PHP. The number of rows is dependent on the number of students queried from the database. The number of columns (e.g. assignment, quizzes) are generated from inputs beforehand. The contents of the columns (excluding the name and the final grade columns) are editable since I need to input some values. And now all I want to do is calculate each row and output the final grade on the Final Grade column using jQuery.

Here is the dynamic part of the table:

```
<?php foreach($students as $student) { ?>
  <tr class='start' id='student<?php echo $student['userId'];?>'>
     <td><?php echo $student['last_name'] . ', ' . $student['first_name'];?></td>
        <?php
          for($i = 0; $i < $assignment; $i++)
          {
             echo "<td class='assignment' contenteditable='true'>0</td>";
          }

          for($i = 0; $i < $seatwork; $i++)
          {
             echo "<td class='seatwork' contenteditable='true'>0</td>";
          }

          for($i = 0; $i < $quiz; $i++)
          {
             echo "<td class='quiz' contenteditable='true'>0</td>";
          }

          for($i = 0; $i < $recitation; $i++)
          {
             echo "<td class='rec' contenteditable='true'>0</td>";
          }

          for($i = 0; $i < $gwork; $i++)
          {
             echo "<td class='gwork' contenteditable='true'>0</td>";
          }
          ?>
          <td id='attendance'contenteditable='true'>0</td>
         <td id='f_grade<?php echo $student['userId'];?>'></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I was successful on iterating on the necessary rows and columns, but now how do I iterate each row and calculate the final grade?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that per column (assignment, quizzes), there is a certain percentage I need to calculate with (e.g. for assignments, 10%). Thus, I'll need to get average of all assignment columns then multiply it by the percentage.

jQuery

```
function compute()
{
    $("tr.start > td:not(:first-child, :last-child)").each(function(obj, val) 
    {
         console.log(val);
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Here's what I've done so far. This code correctly iterates through the necessary columns. The problem is, I seem to be having a hard time in differentiating the rows for each student as well as the columns for each grades.

Sorry xD forgot to mention that I'm new here

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a code writing service.  Show us what you've tried and where it's failing.  If it were me, I would iterate over each $(".start") row, add up the values of all of the applicable `td`s inside that, and assign that value to the final td of that row.

Also note - the td with an id won't work because that will be replicated on each row, and ids must be unique.

Comment: Please place code pertinent to your question IN your question (for readability and completeness).

Comment: Sorry, edit done

Comment: Since you generate the code in PHP, why not do the calculation in PHP as well? Then you can calculate from the raw data and display it on the page, instead of trying to read values back out of the DOM.

Comment: I will need to compute the grades without refreshing the page